# What's the difference between IntTween and StepTween?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a countdown timer which goes from 3 to 1. Visually I do not see a difference and from the docs, I couldn't understand the use case of these two classes.

Thanks!

Comment: compare [IntTween](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/tween.dart#L398) and [StepTween](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/tween.dart#L426)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [`IntTween`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/IntTween-class.html) states (with added emphasis):

> An interpolation between two integers that **rounds**.

The documentation for [`StepTween`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/StepTween-class.html) states:

> An interpolation between two integers that **floors**.

Additionally, `StepTween` states:

> This results in a value that is never greater than the equivalent value from a linear double interpolation. Compare to `IntTween`.

So, for example, if the interpolated value would be, say, 1.9, `IntTween` will round to the *nearest* integer (2) whereas `StepTween` will use the mathematical floor (1).