# Flutter animate CrossAxisalignment with tween

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm searching for a solution to implement a change in the CrossAxisAllignment of a Column using and `AnimatedBuilder`. As the child of the `AnimatedBuilder` I use a Column in which I change the `CrossAxisAlignment` to either start or center.

This was my idea to create the Animation with a Tween but I couldn't find a Tween specificaly for the CrossAxisAlignment:

```
_positionAnimation =
        AlignmentTween(begin: CrossAxisAlignment.start end: CrossAxisAlignment.center).animate(_positionController);
```

This is my `AnimatedBuilder` with the Column as a child to change the alignment.

```
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _positionController,
  builder: (context, child) => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: _positionAnimation.value,
          children: [
            FadeTransition(
              opacity: _animationController,
              child: Text(
                carouselList[_current].title,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            FadeTransition(
              opacity: _animationController,
              child: Text(
                carouselList[_current].paragraph,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
              ),
            )
          ]),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Is there a way to implement the animation of the CrossAxisAlignment with a Tween?

Answer (score 0):

`CrossAxisAlignment` is an enum, and enums values are very specific! there is no interpolation between them or a `lerp` method for them or even a probability to implement one sadly.

But if you want to achive like-effect you can do it using a `Stack` with `Align` (`Alignment` can be interpolated) or `Positioned`.

But if you insist on using a `Flex` you can compine `Flexible` or `Expanded` with an `IntTween` or `StepTween` to get the desired effect.

If the new `Tween` classes are new to you, here is a  [useful link for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433662/whats-the-difference-between-inttween-and-steptween).